boost:python expose const std::string&
I understand std::string is exposed to python by implicit converters that don't need to be registered.
However, const std::string& isn't
I have
class Cal {
  const std::string& get_name() const;
};

and the eqv python class
namespace bp=boost::python;
bp::class_<Cal, Cal*>("Cal")
.add_property("name",
      make_function(&Cal::get_name, bp::return_value_policy<bp::reference_existing_object>()));

and the registration of the converter
bp::to_python_converter<const Cal*, Cal_ptr_to_python_obj>{};

However, from Python when I call
cal.name

I get this error:
No Python class registered for C++ class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >

which I don't understand because std::string converter is implicitly registered
I tried to register a converter for const std::string& but that fails to compile as the bp code tries to take a pointer to const std::string& and then asserts "pointer to reference"

Weird that 1006 highly rated user was not able to find the answer.

@3CxEZiVlQ it is the same person that asked the question 10 years ago .....

@AhmedAEK This is funny.

@AhmedAEK Wait, are you saying an experienced user keeps asking the same question again and again over decades to accumulate thousands of reputation points on Stack Overflow? I suspect they are just testing time loops aka closed time-like curves (CTCs) that recently became affordable thanks to latest developments in quantum mechanics.

@heapunderrun "thousands" - hehe
